# Diffrence in result from PostgreSQL (PostGIS) and SQL Server (Spatial)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, spatial, postgis

I have two points and I have to calculate difference between them.

I using below query in SQL Server.

```
SELECT geography::Point(27.185425, 88.124582, 4326)
       .STDistance(geography::Point(27.1854258, 88.124500, 4326));
```

Its running fine and result is :

```
8.12599260290125
```

Now with same point when I am running below query in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(27.185425 88.124582)',4326),
                   ST_GeomFromText('POINT(27.1854258 88.124500)', 4326));
```

and Now result is :

```
8.20039023523232
```

Can anyone tell me why there is difference in results when calculating distance between two points?

Comment: You shouldn't put points in WKT in PostGIS. You should construct points using `ST_MakePoint(lon,lat)::geography`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things that have caught you out here.

In the SQL Server version using the Point, the order of the coordinate is Lat Lon, eg Y X.  The OGC Point construct is X Y or Lon Lat.

The next is that the PostGIS query you've posted actually returns `8.20039023523232e-005` which while appearing similar to the SQL Server result, is quite a lot smaller.

The last issue is that the PostGIS query is treating the objects as Geometries and doing a cartesian distance on them.  You need to explicitly make them Geographies.

Here's a few ways to do the PostGIS query.  I've swapped the coordinate order

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(88.124582 27.185425)',4326)::geography,
                   ST_GeomFromText('POINT(88.124500 27.1854258)',4326)::geography);

SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(88.124582 27.185425)'),
                   ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(88.124500 27.1854258)'));

-- Adapted from the PostGIS Manual
SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist 
FROM (SELECT
    ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(88.124582 27.185425)') As gg1,
    ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(88.124500 27.1854258)') As gg2
    ) As foo  ;
```

Comment: You shouldn't put points in WKT. You should construct points using `ST_MakePoint(lon,lat)::geography`